# How to use different colorscheme and syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose I want to use this colorscheme:
https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme

I copied the PaperColor.vim file into .vim/colors and made my .vimrc:

```
syntax on
colorscheme PaperColor
background=light
```

Now, I want to use this syntax highlighting for haskell files: https://github.com/raichoo/haskell-vim/tree/master/syntax

There are two syntax highlighting files. Which one am I supposed to use, and where do it put them?

Thanks!

Do I put it in ./vim/syntax and vim auto-loads all files in ./vim/syntax folder?

It seems like to load haskell.vim automatically. But doesn't load cabal.vim. Wondering if it only loads haskell.vim when I open .hs files? I'm trying to make it like that. Can vim load multiple syntax files at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Everything's (mostly) fine. There's a difference between colorschemes and syntax scripts.**

Most *filetypes* (like `python`) in Vim come with a syntax that defines highlight groups (see them via `:highlight python<C-d>`). These particular groups (e.g. `pythonFunction`) are then *linked* to a set of default groups (`:help highlight-groups`, e.g. `Identifier`). A *colorscheme* then provides combinations of foreground / background color and/or formatting like bold and italic (separately for terminals, color terminals, and/or GVIM) for the default groups.

highlight group → default group → color + style
`pythonFunction` → `Identifier` → `term=underline ctermfg=3 guifg=DarkCyan`

So, for a set of beautifully matching colors that please your personal taste, you choose a colorscheme. For you, that would be `colorscheme PaperColor`. **Note** that the `background` needs to be set **before choosing the color** (and you've missed the `:set` command):

```
syntax on
set background=light
colorscheme PaperColor
```

The syntax scripts know how to parse a certain syntax (for you: both *haskell* and *cabal*; what gets activated depends on *filetype detection*, which usually does the right thing, but you could also manually override it (`:setlocal syntax=cabal`); I think the former is for Haskell source code while cabal is a package definition). They basically recognize certain syntax elements, and link them to generic *highlight groups* (like `Statement`, `String`, `Comment`, and so on). Now how these are then colored (e.g. bold green) is determined by your chosen colorscheme.

As you can see, colorschemes and syntax scripts each have a distinct role, and play together. While the former is a global personal choice, the latter is activated based on the detected filetype, which is different for each buffer.